# Why are my peas dying from the bottom up?

Tags: diagnosis, peas

I grow Super Sugar Snap peas in large containers every year, and every year I see the same thing -- around the time they flower, they start dying from the bottom up. This happens quite early -- the attached photo is of the stage where the first peas are starting to appear on the vines. I can still harvest from the plants as the tops are still healthy-looking, but they're gradually dying and will stop producing pretty soon.

Is this part of a normal life cycle for this variety of peas, or is something wrong?

[image: damaged pea plants]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pot bound, it looks like there may be some root rot going on.  Repot and add some perlite to keep the soil aired out the roots need to breath too.